# TFS partial merge from a non-related branch

Tags: git, tfs, version-control

I have a branch (B) which is created from another branch (A) (clone) and another branch (C) that created (clone) from (B). A and B has a relation and also B and C but there is no relation between A and C already. I need to merge some changes from C to A. Please give me suggestions/thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: Any suggestion or solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge changes from one branch to another branch with no direct relation, you need to perform what is called a baseless merge.  Instructions on doing this are located [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668976.aspx).

Hope this helps!